# Yii GridView: Highlight Row Based on Condition

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2

We have a timetable application in our school. We are looking to expand its functionality.

Currently when a class code is searched we get a list of students in that class. We have created a new model for our database that has a list of students with medical requirements.

We'd like the Gridview in our timetable view to highlight the students with a record in our medical table. We are just unsure how to go about this we've never had to highlight in gridview based on a condition.

timetable model;

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['ttLastName', 'ttFirstName', 'ttYearLevel', 'stuId', 'ttClassId'], 'required'],
            [['ttYearLevel'], 'integer'],
            [['ttLastName', 'ttFirstName', 'stId', 'ttClassId'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['stuId'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Student::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['stuId' => 'stuId']],
        ];
    }
```

medical model;

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['amCreatedAt', 'amBackGround', 'amStrategies', 'amCreatedBy'], 'required'],
            [['amCreatedBy', 'stuId'], 'integer'],
            [['amCreatedAt'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['amBackGround', 'amStrategies'], 'string'],
            [['stuId'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Student::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['stuId' => 'stuId']],
        ];
    }
```

timetable gridview;

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            //['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'ttLastName',
            'ttFirstName',
            'ttYearLevel',
            'bceId',
            'ttClassId',

            // 'ttClassId',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated, we don't need the full code just an explanation on how to approach it.

Thank you

Comment: I would like to confirm that you want to higlight the data from your medical model to the gridview of timetable model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ccustomize `rowOptions` property of GridView to add a class for grid row. Then add css to that class to have a background color

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
        // $model is the current data model being rendered
        // check your condition in the if like `if($model->hasMedicalRecord())` which could be a method of model class which checks for medical records.
        if() { 
             return ['class' => 'highlighted_grid_row'];
        }
        return [];
    }
    'columns' => [
        //['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'ttLastName',
        'ttFirstName',
        'ttYearLevel',
        'bceId',
        'ttClassId',

        // 'ttClassId',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: Please, put a comma after the rowOptions function.